# How to get a reliable time from user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

We've built a chat web-app, user get data from APIs first time and then send data back to server with those APIs, and we're using websocket to handle new data (new messages and other stuff).

Today one of our users told us that wrong number of messages showed up in the list of new messages, after hours of investigation I've noticed that user has wrong system time (about 3 minutes difference from our server time).

In our app, we check if user opened that conversation and then send current time back to server (from javascript `new Date()`).

I don't want to user lose any new message, even when they marked that conversation as read and during marking process new message arrived, if I set time from server they will lose that new message, if I use browser time that's not matching exact to our server.

I really don't know handling this case is important or not, and other apps handling this case or not, and if handling this how?

Every bit of help is really appreciated

#### Edit

I don't want to send user check-time on every request, for this reason our app sends server checked time 10 seconds after user interacted with app (marked that as read).

Comment: Timekeeping on the client is completely out of your control.

Comment: ^ that! The usual way to handle this if one needs accurate time keeping is to output a timestamp from the server, and use that as a base instead.

Comment: @adeneo so you telling me that use timestamps as identifier (an absolute incremental identifier) but overlap could happen that timestamp in javascript isn't unique enough (milliseconds).

Comment: Btw I can use exact time from server using microseconds (to increase uniqueness)

Comment: The best you can do is to receive a UTC+00:00 timestamp and then you calculate the time difference in miliseconds. Everytime the user tries to comunicate with the APP, you drift the clock *n* milliseconds. This solved the issue for me, when I tried to make a simple timezoneless clock to work reliably, even when the date is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Send message with something like Last-Event-ID generated from server.

and decide which message you should send. not just user time.

Comment: Thanx @ssskip, the chat is part of an extensive app, in all other parts we've decided not to rely on user's time, but in this case there's lots of other things we must check, one of them is loading newer and older messages, for that (and the fact that our ids are not incremental) we decided to compare timestamps, I was curious if there's a way to get reliable time from user.

Comment: you can't treat user time as real, if u don't want implement event_id, you can send server time during new message sent to client( means last message time) . and compare it. @KiTO